# How to save an image in Qt without having to manually add .jpeg or .png extension?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to save an image to disc and the user can choose to save it as .png or .jpeg. When the FileDialog pops up if I set the image name to img.jpeg it works but if I set it to just img it doesn't save it. How can I fix it?

```
QImage image;
    QString imagePath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName( this,tr("Save File"),"", tr("JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG (*.png)" ));

        QPixmap pm =ui->label2->pixmap();

            if (!pm.isNull() && !imagePath.isEmpty() )
            {
                 image =pm.toImage() ;
                 image.save(imagePath);
            }
```

Comment: Set a default suffix? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#defaultSuffix-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to check if it has an extension, and if it doesn't then add the extension:

```cpp
const QStringList validSuffixes({"png", ".jpg"})

QString imagePath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),"", tr("JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg);;PNG (*.png)" ));

QPixmap pm =ui->label2->pixmap();

if (!pm.isNull() && !imagePath.isEmpty()){
    QFileInfo info(imagePath);
    if(!validSuffixes.contains(info.suffix())){
        imagePath = info.baseName() + ".jpg";
    }
    pm.save(imagePath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can check is the user chose JPEG or PNG and update the imagePath with that chosen extension?